# Merge outputs of different models with different input shapes

Tags: machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am new to Keras. I am trying to merge the output layers of three pretrained models in Keras. Each model has two separate inputs, but of different dimensions, and a Dense layer output.

```
    model1 = MyModel1() #returns keras.engine.training.Model
    model2 = MyModel2() #returns keras.engine.training.Model
    model3 = MyModel3() #returns keras.engine.training.Model

    x = merge([model1(model1.input),
               model2(model2.input),
               model3(model3.input)],
              mode='concat', concat_axis=1)

    # add some trainable layers here...

    # and a final softmax layer
    x = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

    return Model(input=[model1.input,
                        model2.input,
                        model3.input],
                 output=x)
```

Since model?.input returns a list of Tensors, this does not work. I tried different things and nothing seems to work. Is there an easy solution to this problem?

**EDIT:**
Adapted working solution from indraforyou for multiple inputs in each model.

```
    from keras.models import Model
    from keras.layers import Input, Dense, merge


    def MyModel1():
        inp1 = Input(batch_shape=(None,32,))
        inp2 = Input(batch_shape=(None,32))
        x = Dense(8)(inp1)
        y = Dense(8)(inp2)
        merged = merge([x, y], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)
        out = Dense(8)(merged)
        return Model(input=[inp1,inp2], output=out)

    def MyModel2():
        inp1 = Input(batch_shape=(None,10,))
        inp2 = Input(batch_shape=(None,10,))
        x = Dense(4)(inp1)
        y = Dense(4)(inp2)
        merged = merge([x, y], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)
        out = Dense(4)(merged)
        return Model(input=[inp1,inp2], output=out)

    def MyModel3():
        inp1 = Input(batch_shape=(None,12,))
        inp2 = Input(batch_shape=(None,12,))
        x = Dense(6)(inp1)
        y = Dense(6)(inp1)
        merged = merge([x, y], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)
        out = Dense(6)(merged)
        return Model(input=[inp1,inp2], output=out)

    model1 = MyModel1()
    model2 = MyModel2()
    model3 = MyModel3()

    x = merge([model1.output,
               model2.output,
               model3.output],
              mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)

    x = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

    merged =  Model(input=[model1.input[0], model1.input[1],
                           model2.input[0], model2.input[1],
                           model3.input[0], model3.input[1]],
                    output=x)

    merged.summary()
```

Answer (score 4):

<s>The models object is not a callable function.</s> This should fix the problem:

```
x = merge([model1.output,
           model2.output,
           model3.output],
          mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
```

**Updating the working code**

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, merge


def MyModel1():
  inp = Input(batch_shape=(None,32,))
  out = Dense(8)(inp)
  return Model(input=inp, output=out)

def MyModel2():
  inp = Input(batch_shape=(None,10,))
  out = Dense(4)(inp)
  return Model(input=inp, output=out)

def MyModel3():
  inp = Input(batch_shape=(None,12,))
  out = Dense(6)(inp)
  return Model(input=inp, output=out)

model1 = MyModel1()
model2 = MyModel2()
model3 = MyModel3()

x = merge([model1.output,
           model2.output,
           model3.output],
          mode='concat', concat_axis=1)

x = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

merged =  Model(input=[model1.input,
                    model2.input,
                    model3.input],
             output=x)

merged.summary()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but models are callable just like layers [https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). This did not fix my problem.

Comment: thanks for the link, I stand corrected. Although Its working at my end. I am sharing the whole code.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm! I adapted in my post your solution for multiple inputs, but it's basically the same.

Comment: No problem, great that you figured out for multiple inputs case